# Replace MacMini Harddrive with SSD

Tags: mac, mac-mini

Is it possible to replace the hard drive of a MacMini (latest model) with a SSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I recommend [the guide from iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Mac-mini-Model-A1347-Hard-Drive-Replacement/3113/1).

> **Step 1 — Bottom Cover**
>
> - Place your thumbs in the depressions cut into the bottom cover.
> - Rotate the bottom cover counter-clockwise until the white dot painted on the bottom cover is aligned with the ring inscribed on the outer case.
>
> **Step 2**
>
> - Tilt the mini enough to allow the bottom cover to fall away from the outer case.
> - Remove the bottom cover and set it aside.
>
> **Step 3 — Fan**
>
> - Remove the two 11.3 mm T6 Torx screws securing the fan to the logic board near the antenna plate.
>
> **Step 4**
>
> - Lift the ear of the fan nearest the RAM up off the standoff secured to the outer case.
>
> **Step 5**
>
> - Lift the fan out of the mini for enough clearance to access its connector.
> - Carefully pull the fan cables upward to lift the fan connector up out of its socket on the logic board.
> - Remove the fan.
>
> **Step 6 — Cowling**
>
> - Remove the single 3.5 mm T6 Torx screw securing the cowling to the heat sink.
>
> **Step 7**
>
> - Lift the cowling from the end nearest the antenna plate.
> - Rotate the cowling away from the outer case and remove it from the mini.
>
> **Step 8 — Antenna Plate**
>
> - Remove the following screws securing the antenna plate to the mini:
>
>   - Two 6.6 mm T8 Torx screws
>   - Two 5.0 mm T8 Torx or 2.0 mm Hex screws (either will work)
>
> **Step 9**
>
> - Slightly lift the antenna plate from the end closest to the RAM.
> - Carefully pull the antenna plate straight away from the circular rim of the outer case.
> - Do not remove the antenna plate yet. It is still attached to the AirPort/ Bluetooth board
>
> **Step 10**
>
> - Use the tip of a spudger to carefully pry the antenna connector up off the AirPort/Bluetooth board.
>
> **Step 11**
>
> - Remove the antenna plate from the mini.
>
> **Step 12 — Hard Drive**
>
> - Remove the following three screws:
>
>   - One 5.0 mm T8 Torx or 2.0 mm Hex screw (either will work)
>   - One 16.2 mm T6 Torx screw
>   - One 26 mm T6 Torx standoff
>
> **Step 13**
>
> - Carefully pull the wires for both hard drive thermal sensors upward to lift their connectors up and out of their respective sockets on the logic board.
>
> **Step 14**
>
> - Use the flat end of a spudger to pry both the hard drive and optical drive connectors up out of their sockets on the logic board.
>
> **Step 15**
>
> - For enough clearance to remove the hard drive, the logic board must be slightly removed. To accomplish this, two cylindrical rods must be inserted into the holes highlighted in red.
> - Inserting instruments into any logic board holes other than the ones highlighted in red may severely damage the logic board.
> - Insert two tools having a maximum diameter of 2.5 mm into the holes highlighted in red. Be sure they make contact with the outer case below the logic board before proceeding.
> - Carefully pry the tools toward the I/O board. The logic board and I/O board assembly should slightly slide out of the outer case.
> - Cease prying when the I/O board is visibly separated from the outer case. Remove the two tools.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Can you please put the info in your own words in the post, or at least copy and paste a summary of the relevant parts?  Answers that consist only of a link are bad because we can't guarantee that the link will still work in the future.

Comment: @Shinrai No problem. I copied the relevant info from linked site.

Comment: Ive replace the hard drive in older mac minis... its a complete PIA.

Answer (score 0):

There's a special SATA cable (sold separately) that can add second SATA drive to single-drive models of MacMini (2011 & 2012). I'd recommend adding additional drive using special ifixit toolkit (did it by myself)

[Tutorial for MacMini 2011](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+Mac+Mini+Mid+2011+Dual+Hard+Drive+Kit/6634/1), [Tutorial for MacMini 2012](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+Mac+Mini+Late+2012+Dual+Hard+Drive+Kit/11713/1)

Comment: Could you please at least summarize one or both of those tutorials here? Links are okay, but you should always post the information here as well.